# Should I be concerned with the rate of state change in my React Redux app?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, redux

I am implementing/evaluating a "real-time" web app using React, Redux, and Websocket. On the server, I have changes occurring to my data set at a rate of about 32 changes per second.

Each change causes an async message to the app using Websocket. The async message initiates a RECEIVE action in my redux state. State changes lead to component rendering.

My concern is that the frequency of state changes will lead to unacceptable load on the client, but I'm not sure how to characterize  load against number of messages, number of components, etc.

When will this become a problem or what tools would I use to figure out if it is a problem?

Does the "shape" of my state make a difference to the rendering performance? Should I consider placing high change objects in one entity while low change objects are in another entity?

Should I focus my efforts on batching the change events so that the app can respond to a list of changes rather than each individual change (effectively reducing the rate of change on state)?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are actually pretty reasonable questions to be asking, and yes, those do all sound like good approaches to be looking at.

As a thought - you said your server-side data changes are occurring 32 times a second.  Can that information itself be batched at all?  Do you literally need to display every single update?

You may be interested in the "Performance" section of the Redux FAQ, which includes answers on ["scaling"](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#performance-scaling) and [reducing the number of store subscription updates](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#performance-update-events).

Grouping your state partially based on update frequency sounds like a good idea.  Components that aren't subscribed to that chunk should be able to skip updates based on React Redux's built-in shallow equality checks.

I'll toss in several additional useful links for performance-related information and libraries.  My React/Redux links repo has a section on [React performance](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md), and my Redux library links repo has relevant sections on [store change subscriptions](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store.md#store-change-subscriptions) and [component update monitoring](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/devtools.md#component-update-monitoring).

Comment: Thanks! The links were just what I needed.