# Should I store high-throughput, structured sensor data in redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've recently started using React and so far I have built a couple of apps, including one realtime application for manipulating and visualising sensor data. This data consists in high-throughput, structured JSON frames coming from websockets at 100Hz-200Hz.

As my app is quickly growing in complexity, and after learning about Redux through official docs and Dan Abramov's courses, I have found the use of Redux very compelling to manage the visual state of the app, routing, server information, etc.

In my React-non-Redux app everything is kept in local state, but this had a cost in the architectural design. Now, I would like to start refactoring the app to integrate redux. With my limited knowledge at this point, I'm stuck at this architectural decision about  **where to store the sensors streams' data** and the impact on the application rendering and processing performance.

In redux docs there rules of thumb for determining what kind of data should be put into Redux:

- Do other parts of the application care about this data? [YES]
- Do you need to be able to create further derived data based on this
  original data? [YES]
- Is the same data being used to drive multiple components? [YES]
- Is there value to you in being able to restore this state to a given
  point in time (ie, time travel debugging)? [YES]
- Do you want to cache the data (ie, use what's in state if it's
  already there instead of re-requesting it)? [MAYBE]

There have been a couple of threads discussing this, but without any definitive answer. I'm also unable to comment on this (SO noob here):

- [Should I be concerned with the rate of state change in my React Redux app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432370/should-i-be-concerned-with-the-rate-of-state-change-in-my-react-redux-app)
- [Visualizing ImmutableJS data from Redux store in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274972/visualizing-immutablejs-data-from-redux-store-in-a-graph)

I have discovered many different ramifications that I need to learn, including middleware, RxJS, etc. I would like to push development further, but as all of this will take time to grasp, I would like to refer to the community for some directions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently using redux to provide data for widgets and I would say the incoming rate is somewhere around 80-90 hertz and I'm still getting 60 fps on widget canvas'. Like Dan said in his post, there is nothing inherently slow about using redux. However updating your UI 200 times a second is completely unnecessary, I would at least add some middleware (if you don't want to have a server) to redux to congregate updates to at most 60 times a second. Redux might not be that slow but trying to render 200 times a second certainly will be.

I will say however that I recently had to make the same decision you are and saving the datastreams in redux made accessing them across my application much simpler.

I found that using web workers was a good way of combining data into a single update. If you haven't already I would check them out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker. If you decide to go in that direction it will probably help a lot with performance since the workers will be handling the websocket connections directly and causing action dispatches to redux in a more controlled manner.

Comment: Hi Dakota sorry for the late reply, I have been away from development for a while. It makes a lot of sense to throttle the updates to the maximum refresh rate and aggregate frames.